# Fileconveyor not syncing files, even though I get no errors. what am I doing wrong?

Tags: drupal-7, cdn, cloud-hosting, rackspace-cloud

I've followed all of the directions for installing fileconveyor on my server, and much to my surprise, I think I installed everything correctly. I foun [this](http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/syncing-to-cloud-files-with-fileconveyor) article particularly useful.

```
When I run arbitrator.py I get the following output 
2013-02-22 18:21:13,792 - Arbitrator                - WARNING  - File Conveyor is initializing.
2013-02-22 18:21:13,795 - Arbitrator                - WARNING  - Loaded config file.
/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py:110: DeprecationWarning: The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.
  warnings.warn("The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.", DeprecationWarning)
2013-02-22 12:21:13,890 - Arbitrator                - WARNING  - Created 'cloudfiles' transporter for the 'Rackspace Cloud Files' server.
2013-02-22 12:21:13,890 - Arbitrator                - WARNING  - Server connection tests succesful!
2013-02-22 12:21:13,891 - Arbitrator                - WARNING  - Setup: created transporter pool for the 'Rackspace Cloud Files' server.
2013-02-22 12:21:13,893 - Arbitrator                - WARNING  - Setup: initialized 'pipeline' persistent queue, contains 0 items.
2013-02-22 12:21:13,893 - Arbitrator                - WARNING  - Setup: initialized 'files_in_pipeline' persistent list, contains 0 items.
2013-02-22 12:21:13,894 - Arbitrator                - WARNING  - Setup: initialized 'failed_files' persistent list, contains 0 items.
2013-02-22 12:21:13,895 - Arbitrator                - WARNING  - Setup: initialized 'files_to_delete' persistent list, contains 0 items.
2013-02-22 12:21:13,895 - Arbitrator                - WARNING  - Setup: moved 0 items from the 'files_in_pipeline' persistent list into the 'pipeline' persistent queue.
2013-02-22 12:21:13,896 - Arbitrator                - WARNING  - Setup: connected to the synced files DB. Contains metadata for 0 previously synced files.
2013-02-22 12:21:13,974 - Arbitrator                - WARNING  - Setup: initialized FSMonitor.
2013-02-22 12:21:13,976 - Arbitrator                - WARNING  - Fully up and running now.
```

I've double checked the config.xml to make sure it matched the directory where my files are. It seems to be working, it just wont sync the files. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix the secret key error first. You can use this link to generate a key and paste it in [installation_dir]/django/conf/global-settings.py http://www.miniwebtool.com/django-secret-key-generator/

my installation was in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django

Hth,
Sadashiv.